# Is it possible to keep particles orientation relative to the emitter when the emitter is rotated?

Tags: particles

I have a plane with a particle system with display type *Group*. Is it possible to keep particles oriented along plane (1st pic) when I rotate the plane? I'm getting particles as in 2nd picture and that's not what I want.

[image: particle's orientation]

And this is what I want to get after rotating
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check **Rotation**, to make the particle system uses the dupli object's rotation. Using this setting, particle orientation can be tweaked by rotating the dupli object itself:

[image: 1a]

Next, give one of the object's local axis as the particle system's initial rotation. This way, any new particle will be oriented to that axis:

[image: 2a]

Now any new emitted particle will always be correctly oriented:

[image: 3a]