# Make particle instances stand on the plane but rotate randomly

Tags: particles, transforms, instances

I need the particle instances to point up, but with random rotation along the Z axis. How can this be done?

[image: plane with particles]

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5024/is-it-possible-to-keep-particles-orientation-relative-to-the-emitter-when-the-em

Answer (score 1):

Under the *Rotation* settings (which have to be enabled, as they are) increase the **Random** property under *Phase*.

[image: particle rotation settings]